# Accessing Cognito Custom Attributes in a post-confirmation lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a post-confirmation lambda function that writes user attribute information to a dynamoDB table. I've managed to get access to standard user attributes fields in the "event" parameter by doing stuff like

```
event.request.userAttributes.sub
```

but trying to run

```
event.request.userAttributes.role //where role is the name of my custom attribute
```

doesn't seem to work. Anyone know what the proper syntax for this is? And do I need to set any special read permissions for custom attributes? I created this custom attribute a long time after I originally made this user pool, if that changes things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All custom attributes are prefixed with the `custom:` prefix ([Documentation - Custom Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes)).

Therefore (I'll assume you're using JavaScript here- if not feel free to specify and I can change this example), you'd need to use:

`event.request.userAttributes['custom:role']`

You don't need to set any special read permissions- all the user attributes are returned in the `PostConfirmation` lambda.

Comment: suppose a field is not there in cognito user pool. can we add one to cognito user pool for that user from post confirmation lambda ?

Comment: no- custom attributes have to be configured ahead of time. you also want to be careful in doing so because they cannot be deleted and you are limited to 25.